# my xslt is loading css and js files twice

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am using apache and php7 to generate xml file and passing to browser with xslt file to render view.

I have noticed that the browser is loading the css and javascript files in the head section twice.

Below is the header file which i need to include in all views.

**header.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <!-- header.xsl -->
    <xsl:template match="header">
        <!-- content of header -->
        <HEAD>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
            <meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW" />
            <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
            <meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1" />

            <!-- Bootstrap -->
            <link href="/assets/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
            <link href="/assets/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
            <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
            <script src="/assets/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
            <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
            <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files  as needed -->
            <script src="/assets/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

            <link href="/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

            <link href="/assets/datatables/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
            <script src="/assets/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
            <script src="/assets/datatables/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>           
            <script src="/assets/datatables.net-buttons/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
            <script src="/assets/datatables.net-select/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>

            <xsl:element name="link">
                <xsl:attribute name="rel">
                    stylesheet
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="type">
                    text/css
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="href">/stylesheets/simple-sidebar.css?<xsl:value-of select="/response/header/timestamp" /></xsl:attribute>             
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="link">
                <xsl:attribute name="rel">
                    stylesheet
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="type">
                    text/css
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="href">/stylesheets/ccp.css?<xsl:value-of select="/response/header/timestamp" /></xsl:attribute>                
            </xsl:element>

            <link href="/assets/fancytree/dist/skin-lion/ui.fancytree.css" rel="stylesheet" />

            <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/images/ccp.ico" />
            <!--[if IE]><link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/ccp.ico"/><![endif] --><!-- Internet Explorer -->

            <!-- flot -->
            <script src="/assets/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
            <script src="/assets/flot/jquery.flot.time.js"></script>

            <script src="/assets/moment/moment.js"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/jquery-depends-on/dependsOn.min.js"></script>

            <!-- Include Fancytree skin and library -->
            <link href="/assets/fancytree/dist/skin-bootstrap/ui.fancytree.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
            <script src="/assets/fancytree/dist/src/jquery.fancytree.js"></script>
            <script src="/assets/fancytree/dist/src/jquery.fancytree.dnd.js"></script>
            <script src="/assets/fancytree/dist/src/jquery.fancytree.edit.js"></script>

            <xsl:element name="script">
                <xsl:attribute name="language">
                    javascript
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="type">
                    text/javascript
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="src">/javascripts/api.js?<xsl:value-of select="/response/header/timestamp" /></xsl:attribute>              
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="script">
                <xsl:attribute name="language">
                    javascript
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="type">
                    text/javascript
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="src">/javascripts/ccp.js?<xsl:value-of select="/response/header/timestamp" /></xsl:attribute>              
            </xsl:element>

            <xsl:element name="link">
                <xsl:attribute name="rel">
                    stylesheet
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="type">
                    text/css
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="media">
                    print
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="href">/stylesheets/print.css?<xsl:value-of select="/response/header/timestamp" /></xsl:attribute>              
            </xsl:element>

            <title>
                <xsl:value-of select="/response/header/title" />
                - Connectivity Compliance Portal (CCP)
            </title>
            <xsl:if test="/response/header/server">
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!--</xsl:text> <xsl:value-of select="/response/header/server" /> <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">--&gt;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </HEAD>

        <div class="container-fluid" id="top_section">

        </div>

        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper" class="hidden-print">
        </div>
        <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div id="myModalError" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        </div>  

    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template name="footer">
        <FOOTER>

        </FOOTER>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is a sample of an xsl main file that I am using

**user_dcsn.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:import href="header.xsl" />

    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8"
        omit-xml-declaration="yes" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" indent="no"
        media-type="text/html" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="body">

        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
        </div>

        <!-- content of other element -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="footer" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML**

this is echoed to browser

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/xslt/user_dcsn.xsl"?>
<response>
  <header>
    <api_status>1</api_status>
    <api_response>success</api_response>
    <http_status>200</http_status>
    <http_response>ok</http_response>
    <format>xml</format>
    <csrf>c982afaddd89be70147e788e9f216915</csrf>
    <error>false</error>
    <quiet>false</quiet>
    <token>c982afaddd89be70147e788e9f216915</token>
    <user>UddinS2</user>
    <title>DC Standard Networks</title>
    <description>Displays standard networks which are available for use</description>
    <nav>
      <container>
        <title>Users</title>
        <link>#</link>
        <theme>#007c92</theme>
        <sub_modules>
          <title>Getting Started</title>
          <link>#</link>
          <theme>#007c92</theme>
          <menuitem>
            <title>File - CM Template v6.3</title>
            <link>/library/templates/FW-LB-CommsMatrix-Template-v6.3.xls</link>
          </menuitem>          
        </sub_modules>
      </container>
    </nav>
    <version>7.0</version>
    <server>1</server>
    <timestamp>1502353988</timestamp>
  </header>
  <body>
    <recordset>
      <record>
        <id>17218037</id>
        <network>x.x.x.x</network>
        <routing_domain>x.x.x.x</routing_domain>
        <zone_name>Database (D1)</zone_name>
        <zone>x.x.x.x</zone>
        <seczone>x.x.x.x</seczone>
        <netzone>x.x.x.x</netzone>
        <loczone>x.x.x.x</loczone>
        <location>x.x.x.x</location>
        <vlan>x.x.x.x</vlan>
        <vrf>x.x.x.x</vrf>
        <sw>x.x.x.x</sw>
        <dsw>x.x.x.x</dsw>
        <lbmode>Not assigned</lbmode>
        <utilization>23%</utilization>
        <free_ips>47</free_ips>
        <source>x.x.x.x</source>
      </record>
    </recordset>
  </body>
</response>
```

below is screenprint where you can see duplicate sources being loaded twice. it doesn't happen all the time

[image]

[image]

Below are pictures of the response/request headers for both the ccp.js files

[image]

[image]

Comment: So what exactly are you testing with, is "the browser" a particular browser? And if the issue is about loading CSS and script files twice, then for demonstrating the problem and allow others to reproduce the issue you might want to trim the example to a minimal but complete snippet. Is there any URL we can load the see the issue? What does the browser's network monitor show about the request/response headers?

Comment: updated with xml and pictures